# ¿como cargar scripts de una carpeta con subcarpetas en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito una forma mas simple de cargar mis script ya que lo usan otras personas y a su vez diferente sistema operativo que son entre linux y windows al momento uso **execfile()** pero tienes que cambiar el formato de la direciones tambien intente con **sys.path.insert(0, PATH)** pero no tiene acceso los recursos que importe en el archivo archivo principal

```
ruta = "/home/lacosta/Documents/"
capa0 = "LIBRERIAS/TOOL/"
capa1 = "LIBRERIAS/BAIL/"
capa2 = capa1
# cargando funciones
# capa 0
execfile(ruta + capa0 + "Loadmain.py")
execfile(ruta + capa0 + "funcion_tool.py")
execfile(ruta + capa0 + "funcion_mathGeo.py")
```

con el **sys.path.insert(0, PATH)** ya solo tengo que dar la direccion de la carpeta pero las funciones no reconoces que ya se importo otros modulos como el math y vector se importan antes que loadmain y marcar error que no se a definido

```
FREECADPATH = '/home/lacosta/Documents/LIBRERIAS/'
sys.path.insert(0, FREECADPATH)
import math
from Part import *
from FreeCAD import Vector, Rotation, Placement
import Draft
from TOOL.Loadmain import *
```

Comment: Deberías leer sobre la diferencia entre [modulo y paquete](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages). Lo tuyo sería lo segundo (una carpeta que contiene varios módulos o quizás sub-carpetas). Haciéndolo en la forma apropiada (con su `__init__.py`) la vía de cambiar el path debería funcionar, pero sigue sin ser la mejor. Lo correcto sería hacer un `setup.py` como parte de tu paquete para que se pueda instalar con `pip install` en la ruta estándar (o en un virtualenv) aunque esto ya no es trivial.

Comment: También, la forma de crear una ruta de modo que no dependa del operativo, es usar las funciones que tienes en [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html)